# Shuffling a list of functions with random.shuffle

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I have some functions:

```
def feeling():
    ...

def homesick():
    ...

def miss():
     ...
```

I'd like to put them in a list, shuffle them, and call each of them in succession:

```
import random
prompts = [feeling, homesick, miss]
```

My idea was to call each function like this:

```
random.shuffle(prompts)()
```

But this throws a

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get this to work?

Comment: `random.shuffle(prompts)()`? What? Just do `random.shuffle(prompts)` and then `print(prompts)`.

Comment: `random.shuffle` performs in place shuffling and returns nothing (`None`). It follows that you cannot `__call__` a `None` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a task to choose one of these functions at random. Here's a small demo does what you're doing, but correctly.

```
>>> f = [sum, max, min]
>>> random.shuffle(f)
>>> f.pop()([1, 2, 3])   # looks like we picked max. Alternatively, `f[0](...)`
3
```

Or, if it's only *one* function you want, there's no need to use `random.shuffle` at all. Use `random.choice` instead.

```
>>> random.choice(f)([1, 2, 3])
>>> 3
```

---

### Why Your Error Occurs

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) performs an *inplace* shuffling, as the docs mention.

```
>>> y = list(range(10))
>>> random.shuffle(y)
>>> y
[6, 3, 4, 1, 5, 8, 9, 0, 7, 2]
```

So, when you call the function, expect nothing in return. In other words, expect `None` in return.

Further, calling `()` on an object invokes its `__call__` method. Since `NoneType` objects do not have such a method, this errors out with `TypeError`. For an object to be callable, you'd need -

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __call__(self, y):
        return self.x + y
```

```
>>> f = Foo(10)
>>> f(20)
30
```

As an exercise, try removing `__call__` and rerunning the code. Calling `f(20)` should give you the same error.

---